# Naming conventions for complex getters in Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions, getter-setter

I was reading this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054.aspx) about the usage of properties and methods in .NET. It points out why and when to use properties or methods.

> Properties are meant to be used like
>   fields, meaning that properties should
>   not be computationally complex or
>   produce side effects.

Otherwise one should use methods.

I was asking myself how you could express this difference in Java.

What is your opinion?

Comment: "complex getter" sounds like an oxymoron to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was asking myself how you could express this difference in Java.

Just don't use the `get` prefix on the method, as it normally implies that the method will be cheap (as getters usually only access fields, delegate to other getters, or perform fairly simple calculations based on other getters). For example, if a class has this interface:

```
class Blob {
    long getLength() { ... }
    ByteBuffer getBytes() { ... }
    Sha1Checksum getChecksum() { ... }
}
```

... it would seem that getting the length, contents, and checksum from the `Blob` are equally costly. If we did like this, instead:

```
interface Blob {
    long getLength() { ... }
    ByteBuffer getBytes() { ... }
    Sha1Checksum calculateChecksum() { ... }
}
```

... it becomes clear(er) that we can expect `calculateChecksum()` to be more expensive than the other operations, as its name says it's going to do more than just get something.

To a certain degree, the complexity is an implementation issue that shouldn't be seen in the interface (maybe I decide to calculate the checksum eagerly when the `Blob` is constructed?), but there are occasions where it makes sense to make a distinction.

Answer (score 3):

I just don't agree with what that article says. Properties are syntactic sugar, otherwise you'd just use fields.

The point of getters/properties is **encapsulation** - the user does not know whether it's simply a field, something you compute every time or a random value.

This means that for me, every class in Java that is not a "Data Structure" has getters and setters for its fields (that need to be accessible).

Comment: I agree with the article. The user of the class should be able to roughly understand why there is a GetXXX()-Method instead of a simple property. I would also expect to get the same value each time I call a property of a class (if it has not been changed, of course).

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If all the operations are completely internal then `getSomething()` is okay even for complex implementation - the whole point of getters/setters/properties is to encapsulate implementation details and hide them, even if in the future they change to be something complex.

An exception to this is if the operation is so complex it might significant amount of time or resources (e.g. download some data from the internet). In that case I might use a different method name - it kind of breaks encapsulation but it's useful and practical.

If the getter has any **observable side effects**, however, I would probably not use the simple `getSomething()` convention, to avoid confusion. Maybe I'll use `updateAndReturn()` or `getAndComplexify()` or `getFromWeb()` or stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

C# Property is basically Java getter and setter in one. If I need use both geters and setters for one instance, I always choose property. In java, I don't have this option.

Comment: ... the msdn examples show C++, not C# code. Does C# has 'properties' too?

Comment: The msdn article is about .NET. And C# has properties, just like C++/CLI.